# Visual Studio 2010 Compiling C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code snippet.  This is a c file in visual studio 2010.  If i try to compile this with the line: int hello = 10; commented out it will compile just fine.  If I comment that line in it will not compile.  Am I missing something or should I not be using Visual Studio 2010 to compile C code.  If this is a Visual Studio problem can anyone recommend a easy to use IDE / Compiler that I can for C.

Thank You

```
int* x = (int*) calloc(1, sizeof(int));

*x = 5;

//int hello = 10;

printf("Hello World!  %i", *x);

getchar();
```

Comment: "it will not compile": care to tell us the compiler error?

Comment: What compilation error do you get?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't have declarations (like `int hello = 10;`) after non-declarations (like `*x = 5;`) in C89, unlike C99 or C++.

MSVC 2010 still does not support C99.

Comment: I guess 11 years isn't quite enough time for a multi-billion dollar corporation to implement a standard.  Seriously, what could be the reason for the lack of support?

Answer (score 1):

you can still declare variables after coding. just change the "yourProject.c" file to "yourProject.cpp" and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

typecasting a `malloc` return pointer in C is a bad practice and has undefined results.

Comment: Sure, it's a bad practice but it has defined results.

Comment: you should NEVER cast a malloc return pointer in C . in C++ its a different story